# Executing a commandline from JConsole

Tags: command-line, j

I've recently discovered the joy of going through JConsole.exe instead of J.exe to run various scripts. There's generally a noticeable performance gain.

However, sometimes I need to use `wd winexec` (calling ad-hoc programs for example) and in the console, `11!:0` (`wd`) support is not available.

Is there a way to send a command from JConsole.exe to the regular Windows command line interpreter? Or maybe a workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might try the task script. See the script itself for documentation.
 J6: `~system/packages/misc/task.ijs'`,
 J7: `~system/main/task.ijs`

It contains utilities such as `fork_jtask_`, `spawn_jtask_`, `shell_jtask_`

You can load the script in both versions using: `require 'task'`